# Are there any singles (not EPs) with titles different from those of the songs they include?

Tags: history, vinyl

Record singles of the Vinyl Era were usually named after their A-side song (since this song was intended to draw the attention of the audience) or had a title composed of their A-side songs’ titles (like “Let's Spend the Night Together/Ruby Tuesday” by the Rolling Stones).

Have there been any examples of singles titled “X” that contained two (or maybe even three) songs of equal importance, *neither* of which was titled “X”? In other words, have there been any examples of so-called "double A-side singles" under their own distinct titles, not borrowed from the names of their songs?

Comment: Do misprints count? I've found the single [Spreadeagle / Capability Brown](https://www.discogs.com/Spreadeagle-Capability-Brown-Nightingale-Lane-Liar-/release/5714767), but the A-side track is actually Scipio... I've found many occurrences of misprinted B-side, but misprints on A-side are not that common.

Comment: This is a list question, i.e. every answer might be valid. Such questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

'Mike Oldfield's Single' from 1973

UK Track listing:

- "Mike Oldfield's Single (Theme from Mike Oldfield's album 'Tubular Bells')" - (Oldfield) 4:36
- "Froggy Went A-Courting" - (traditional, arr. Oldfield) 4:30

USA Track listing:

- "Tubular Bells (Now the Original Theme from The Exorcist)" - (Oldfield) 3:18
- "Tubular Bells" - (Oldfield) 4:39

[Link to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Oldfield%27s_Single)

SO, if you take the *USA* release, this ticks the boxes . . .

[image: Mike Oldfields Single]

Comment: I'm not sure if "Tubular Bells (Now the Original Theme from The Exorcist)" and "Tubular Bells" could be considered "_two songs of equal importance_", as the question states, but thank you.